# Should I invalidate intrinsic content size for the whole hierarchy?

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, uistackview, intrinsic-content-size

Suppose I have the following view hierarchy with Auto Layout enabled:

`UIStackView
|__ OuterCustomView (overridden intrinsic content size)
    |__ UILabel
    |__ InnerCustomView (overridden intrinsic content size)
        |__UILabel
        |__UILabel`

The labels inside `InnerCustomView` have dynamically changeable text and font. Whenever a change happens, I call `InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` (Xamarin syntax) on the `InnerCustomView` instance.

The question is - do I also need to invalidate it manually on the containing `OuterCustomView`, or is the framework clever enough to take everything from there and re-layout everything up to the topmost `UIStackView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to invalidate intrinsic content size manually. 
After calling the method `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` for your view system recursively updates all superviews in hierarchy.